# Is Python's os.fstat available on every platform?

Tags: python, python-3.x, stat

The documentation on `os.stat()` and `os.fstat()` is somewhat confusing about this. On `os.stat()` it says that on some platforms, it also accepts file descriptors and that the `os.supports_fd` set can be used to check if that's the case. On `os.fstat()` it says nothing about platforms, but that, as of Python 3.3, it is equivalent to `os.stat()`.

Does equivalent mean "alias" here, and that on systems where `os.stat()` does not support file descriptors, I can not use them at all, or does it mean, that on such systems I just have to use `os.fstat()` instead?

Furthermore are there any widely used platforms, that do not support using file descriptors for `stat` anyway, or is this just some kind of "there might be platforms not supporting it, but we don't know of any"?